# Unable to open appointment created with Windows Appointments API in Outlook 2016

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, uwp

Since 6th of September, I'm unable to open any appointment created with my UWP app using [Appointments API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appointments) in Outlook 2016. If I try to do this I get an error:

*Sorry, we're having trouble opening this item. This could be temporary, but if you see it again you might want to restart Outlook.*

Error code is 0x80070057 (MAPI_E_INVALID_PARAMETER). This issue applies to Office Outlook for PC only. My app was deployed using both Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017.

I'm able to:

- create an appointment with Appointments API and open it in Calendar app/Outlook Web/Outlook on the mobile,
- create an appointment with Calendar app and open it in Outlook 2016/Calendar app/Outlook Web/Outlook on the mobile

Here is what I found:

- all appointments created with the API fails if I try to open them in Outlook 2016 (even very basic one, with just a subject *test*, empty body and 30 min of duration)
- the issue does not depend on the Windows version (same result with appointments created with previous version of the SDK on Windows 10.0.14393 - it worked until September 6th)
- I am able to open all appointments created before September 6th (regardless of the version of Windows or Outlook); appointments created after this date fails to open (checked on multiple PCs and calendars even on different Office365 tenants, fails even in Outlook 2016 on Windows 8.1)
- checked on different versions of Office 2016 (1708, 1707, 1611) - same results for appointments created before and after September 5th

Here is an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/735

**UPDATE** I used OutlookSpy tool to look into the properties of the problematic appointment and it turned out that most of the appointment's properties are null.

Comment: Thank you for feedback, we have reported it.

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved after installing November updates.